# Why this black box and how to remove it

Tags: images, imagemagick

Generated images from a file

```
cat file.txt | while read line; do
    for word in $line; do
        convert -background none -pointsize 72 \
                -fill orange label:"\ $word" \
                "$word".png
    done
done
```

Images generated as output

> **and.png**
>
> [image: and.png]

Append those images in one image

```
  convert \( regenerated.png and.png in.png +append \) \
          \( the.png from.png carbons.png +append \) \
          \( 5.png 6.png G3P.png carbons.png +append \) \
          -append   append_row.png
```

Image generated as output

> **append_row.png**
>
> [image: append_row.png]

Append this image on another image

```
convert +append append_row.png \
        -trim +repage \
        wall.jpg  +swap -gravity center -geometry +0-3 \
        -composite  anno_undercolor.jpg
```

Image generated as output

> **anno_undercolor.jpg**
>
> [image: anno_undercolor.jpg]

Why there is blackbox and how to remove it from final image?
(Tried but no success)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a transparent background, `-background none` or `-background transparent` work.

```
convert \( regenerated.png and.png in.png +append \) \
        \( the.png from.png carbons.png +append \) \
        \( 5.png 6.png G3P.png carbons.png +append \) \
        -background none -append append_row.png
```

[image]

Related:

- [Append an Array of Images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append_array) (ImageMagick v6 Examples – Multi-Image Layers)